# In asp.net refernce a parent page's control from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I had a DropDownList on the page that I reference in JavaScript like this:

```
var ProjectsDropDownList = '<%= ProjectsDropDownList.ClientID %>';
```

However, I had to move the DropDownList up to the parent IFrame.

How do I reference that control that is now in the parent IFrame from the child IFrame in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your control still has the same `id` after you move it to the parent frame, you can do:

```
var movedElement = window.parent.document.getElementById(
    "<%= ProjectsDropDownList.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: When I try that I get "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ProjectsDropDownList' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @user390480, I see, I thought you were moving the control on the client side, but it appears you moved it into another ASP.NET page on the server side. Does the code that interacts with the control really still have to reside in the subframe? Because there is no easy way for the two pages to share information about `ProjectsDropDownList`, and using e.g. session state to do that would be overkill IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I copied it from one asp.net page to another.  The child IFrame is a result of a third-party tab control that lets me put other pages in tabs.  The tabs are in IFrames.  So, I need the child IFrames to access the ProjectsDropDownList in the parent so it knows what project the user selected.

Comment: @user390480, maybe the markup of the parent frame is static enough for you to hardcode the dropdown's `ClientID` in the subframe script? (I realize it's not an optimal solution, but session state wouldn't be either...)

Comment: I viewed the source to get the generated ID and strangely the ID is ProjectsDropDownList.  (wasn't expecting that.)  So it's working now.  
var ProjectsDropDownList = window.parent.document.getElementById('ProjectsDropDownList');
Thanks.